# Delete uploaded photos

Tags: onedrive

The Photos app is configured to upload my photos to OneDrive, which, the connection permitting, works fine.

However, these photos are also kept in my phone's local storage. With "only" 16GiB, I would like to keep them only in OneDrive to free up space.

Can I go to the Photos app and delete all then camera photos? Will they still exist in OneDrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Once the pictures are saved to OneDrive, you have to explicitly remove them either through the website, or through the OneDrive app. One thing to be aware of, on phones that have a "raw" version, as well as the jpg version, the link between the two can be lost, which then means they can end up showing duplicate if you did want to copy them back.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, but I think the question was about deleting them off the phone, but your answer is how to delete them from OneDrive?

Comment: @ChrisW because "Yes" is too short an answer; I've just elaborated as to what would cause them to not exist on OneDrive

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 things you need to verify before you delete the photos:

1. Check settings -> Photos + Camera -> Auto Upload -> Onedrive and verify if you are uploading best quality photos. If yes, you are good move on to next step. If no, then you just have to take a backup of the photos and replace them in Onedrive via Web/PC.
2. On your phone, goto Photos app and check if any photos are pending to be uploaded. If yes, then upload them.
3. Goto Onedrive app/Onedrive.com and check "SkyDrive camera roll" if all the photos are already uploaded.

Once you are doubly sure, you can safely delete them from the phone. Also don't forget to check for Videos too in case you want them uploaded to OneDrive and removed from phone.

Answer (score -2):

There is no automatic delete one uploaded to overdrive, Google, box, or Dropbox.

The solution is to download titanium backup then label the dcim folder and create a scheduled delete say once a week at 12 pm. Just one way.

I'm assuming at some point the manufactures will add the feature as it's a common request

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Titanium Backup is an Android app. This site is for Windows Phone.